# php preg_replace no result and error but not error message

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When Run The following code،My php script is not run and not show error message.

```
<?php
    $content = '<p>Hi </p> <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com/article/2016/09/05/%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%ac%db%8c-%d9%82%d8%b5%d8%af-%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af-%d8%b3%d8%b1%d9%85%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%87-%da%af%d8%b0%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c-%d8%b9%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85%db%8c-%d8%b1%d8%a7-%d8%af%d8%b1/" ><b>ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد</b></a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com" ><b>بهنام</b></a>.</p>';
    $content = preg_replace('/(The post)+(.)+(appeared first)+(.)+(\.)*/i', '', $content);
    echo $content;
```

I Want remove every thing from "The post" until the end dot-from content varible string.

My goal is dynamicly remove

```
The post <a rel="nofollow" href=""><b>ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد</b></a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com" ><b>بهنام</b></a>.
```

from end of content(RSS description).

I think this problem is because value of the $content is unicode(persian).

**When remove href of link from content variable Output is true.**

Comment: Are you trying to remove EVERYTHING from "The post" until the end or just the words "The post", "appeared first on"?

Comment: I want remove EVERYTHING from "The post" until the end

Comment: Do you mean the result for the string above should be `<p>Hi </p> <p></p>`? Try [`preg_replace('/The post.+appeared first.+\./ui', '', $content);`](https://ideone.com/oLi2zC)

Comment: Yes-thank you- this code is correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct Solution is :

```
$content = preg_replace('/The post.+appeared first on.+\./ui', '', $content);
```

Thanks to wiktor-stribiżew

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this approach is suitable for you.

```
$content = preg_replace('|<p>The post(.)*|', '', $content);
```

My first solution:

```
$contentToReplace[] = '/The post/';
$contentToReplace[] = '/appeared first on/';

$content = preg_replace($contentToReplace, '', $content);
```

Comment: thanks but I want removed "The post .... appeared first on .... " AND the strings that between "the post" and "appeared first on" and to the end

Comment: Basically the output will look like:
    
    Hi
     ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد  بهنام.`

Comment: Not output is "Hi"

Comment: ok, now i know what you are trying to do. Check my answer again, added a second solution.

Comment: your solution is like my code.When remove href of link from content variable Output is true.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
$content = '<p>Hi </p> <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href=""><b>ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد</b></a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com" ><b>بهنام</b></a>.</p>';
$result = preg_replace(
          array('/The post/', '/appeared first on/'),
          array('', ''),
          $content
);
echo $result;
```

Comment: thanks but I want removed "The post .... appeared first on .... " AND the strings that between "the post" and "appeared first on" and to the end

Comment: only "Hi" will be left then?

Comment: Yes result is "Hi"

Comment: $content = '<p>Hi </p> <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href=""><b>ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد</b></a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com" ><b>بهنام</b></a>.</p>';
    $content = explode("<p>",$content);
    print_r( $content);

Answer (score 0):

`$content = preg_replace('/The post(.)*/i', '', $content);`

Will suffice with what you want. The `.` means everything but newline, so you don't need all of those extra fluff.

Answer (score 0):

Use a far superior `DOM` approach:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<p>Hi </p> <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com/article/2016/09/05/%d8%a7%d9%84-%d8%ac%db%8c-%d9%82%d8%b5%d8%af-%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%af-%d8%b3%d8%b1%d9%85%d8%a7%db%8c%d9%87-%da%af%d8%b0%d8%a7%d8%b1%db%8c-%d8%b9%d8%b8%db%8c%d9%85%db%8c-%d8%b1%d8%a7-%d8%af%d8%b1/" ><b>ال جی قصد دارد سرمایه گذاری عظیمی را در حوزه رباتیک انجام دهد</b></a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="http://sample.com" ><b>بهنام</b></a>.</p>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED); 
$dom->removeChild($dom->doctype);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements_to_be_removed = $xpath->query("//p[starts-with(text(), 'The post ')]");
foreach ($elements_to_be_removed as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}

// just to check
echo $dom->saveHTML();
# <p>Hi </p>
?>
```

This removes every `p` where the text starts with "The post ".

Comment: Not is optimize

Comment: @BehnamRasouli: What does your comment mean?